# Nested objects inside React components using Redux and Immutable.js.

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

Using the great [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate) project. However all examples I've found regarding putting together the pieces (even in the boilerplate :/) of react, redux, and immutable.js are trivial. My app is real and we have nested objects, nested arrays etc.

**My question(s)...**

Is this the correct pattern to utilize immutable.js in the context of react component in a react-redux app? Should immutable.js methods be used in the component or should there be logic elsewhere (selector? other?) so the components consume plain JS objects?

If this is incorrect, what is the preferred pattern to tie the pieces together?

```
    <IconMenu>
      {this.props.card.get('related_cards').map(card => (
        <MenuItem
          key={card.getIn(['stream', 'id'])}
          primaryText={card.getIn(['stream', 'name'])}
          onTouchTap={this.onTouchTap.bind(this, card.getIn(['stream', 'id']))}>
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </IconMenu>
```

Here we are simply iterating over the `related_cards` array and showing each `stream` objects name. (The parent component contains an Immutable.Map of `cards` that is supplied via redux store)

Here is the single `card` object (in JS form for your readability) supplied to the component via `this.props.card`:

[image]

I'm asking because I've seen many conflicting examples, some use the raw `toJS()` immutable.js method in their selector OR in the component, others curse `toJS()`'s existence and say thats not using the library correctly.

---

For some more context... our `cards` come via a selector:

```
export const selectCards = () => (state) => state.get('cards');
```

And mapStateToProps

```
export const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => createStructuredSelector({
  cards: selectCards(),
});
```

Comment: are you just asking whether to use `toJS` or not?

Comment: Don't use `toJS`. You want all your component params to be immutable so fast comparison is possible. I'm assuming you are using some kind of "pure" rendering (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/pure-render-mixin.html). In your case you are passing scalar types to `MenuItem` but if you'd pass the whole `card` object/immutable Map then doing `toJS` on them would negate the benefit of using Immutable in the first place.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv not using any pure rendering. Performance is fine, more concerned about if this is the correct way to use immutable.js with react/redux

Comment: Then why are you using Immutable in the first place? Ideally you wouldn't want to pollute your components with Immutable code, it's yet another dependency and you want as few of those as possible. No way of doing that if you use ImmutableJS.

Comment: What I want to say is that I don't see any advantages to using Immutable if you're components are not pure. You are introducing a dependency that is deeply tied to all your code but adds no benefits.

Comment: The above component is pure, as I understand it. Is it not? It "always returns the same result for the same inputs"